# My javascript hint script does not work. Accessing and manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript

**Knowledge level:** Beginner

**What I expect from my code**:

1. The user clicks on a class named open.
2. The textNode within 'open' gets replaced with a - sign.
3. Then I go to the first child of the parent of that class which is an `h2` tag and get the title in order to place it within the sibling of 'open' named 'info'.
4. At last info turns visible.

The ternary operator is to check if we have only a `nodeType` of 3 within the `firstChild`. If yes get the text, if not then get the entire innerHTML. 
Since I get a html collection from `getElementsByClassName` I tend to create a loop so that I can modify the style.

**Why I do this or don't use jQuery:**
I am trying to push myself and learn how to effectively manipulate the dom without third party libraries. I would appreciate hints on improving my code but please keep the basic structure the same as I am still not into advanced short cuts and I am trying to learn not copy.

**Problem** I am not sure how "correct" my idea of manipulating the dom is. I could not get this to work, neither do I know how to effectively tell javascript to handle only the currently clicked element.

http://jsfiddle.net/r7bL6vLy/28/

```
function wrapper () {
    var open = document.getElementsByClassName(open);
    function trigger (){
        var info = this.nextSibling;
        var getTitle = this.parentNode.firstChild.(nodeType == 3 ? textContent : innerHTML)

        this.removeChild(textContent);
        this.appendChild(document.createTextNode('-'));

        info.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getTitle + 'details'));
        info.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
        open[i].addEventListener('click', trigger, false);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='A'>
    <h1>Stackoverflow Question</h1>
    <div class='open'>+</div>    
    <div class='info'>Content A...</div> 
</div>

<div id='B'>
    <h1>Stackoverflow Question</h1>
    <div class='open'>+</div>    
    <div class='info'>Content B...</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `this.nextSibling` will give you the textNode representing the whitespace between the elements. Use `.this.nextElementSibling` instead.
- You don't need to do any traversal to change the `+` to a `-` since you already have the `open` element. Just assign it the new value.

  ```
  this.textContent = "-";
  ```
- To assign the `h2` content, simple use `.previousElementSibling.textContent` and assign it to `info.textContent`

  ```
  info.textContent = this.previousElementSibling.textContent
  ```

Some things you were doing wrong were:

- using invalid syntax here:

  ```
  var getTitle = this.parentNode.firstChild.(nodeType == 3 ? textContent : innerHTML)
  ```

  Should have been an `if` statement, though the condition doesn't really seem necessary. You can use `.textContent` on an element too, as long as you don't need the `HTML` representation.

  Technically you could do this:

  ```
  var child = this.parentNode.firstElementChild;
  var getTitle = child[child.nodeType === 3 ? "textContent" : "innerHTML"];
  ```

  ...but that's pretty ugly. Avoid clever tricks like this.
- Using `textContent` as a reference to an element:

  ```
  this.removeChild(textContent);
  ```

Things that could be improved:

- When changing text, favor manipulating `.textContent` over creating new text nodes. The existing nodes are mutable and so can be reused.
- If you want to copy a section of the DOM to a new location, don't use `.innerHTML` but instead use `.cloneNode(true)`.

  ```
  var copy = myElem.cloneNode(true);
  targetElem.appendChild(copy);
  ```

  Otherwise you're taking the DOM nodes, serializing them to HTML and then immediately parsing the HTML into new nodes. All that string manipulation can be avoided simply by cloning.

Comment: hey squint. About that first point...I understand but I think I have trouble visualizing it. Can you somehow show me an example of that first sentence? The whitespace part kind of confuses me

Comment: @Asperger: Hard to show whitespace, except to explain that when you typed the HTML, you used `newline` characters and `tab` or `space` characters to give the HTML nice indentation. Those are text characters just like any other. So if you have `<div>foo</div> bar <div>baz</div>` you have an `element` followed by a `textNode` followed by another `element`. Now imagine the `bar` is just your formatting spaces. It's still a text node.

Comment: Oh! That is pretty bad. I was not aware that it actually affects those.

Comment: Yep, older versions of IE didn't represent white space but now basically anything in the HTML is represented as a node, so you'll usually use `.nextElementSibling`, `.previousElementSibling`, `.firstElementChild` and `.lastElementChild`.

Comment: Im interested about the bad syntax of my ternary operator. Is the logic simply redundant or just the syntax wrong? The idea was toget the entire innerHTML if nodeType is not pure text and get the text only if there are no other html elements but I guess that Is somewhat stupid.

Comment: @Asperger: The syntax was incorrect. It wouldn't run. If you wanted to represent the entire structure, I still wouldn't use `.innerHTML`. You can clone a DOM structure using `.cloneNode(true)`, where `true` means *"clone descendants as well"*. Then just `.appendChild(my_clone)` where you want it.

Comment: I heared there were security holes with innerHTML apart from all that. Never heared of cloning. It is like copy paste. Nice

Comment: I want to transfer you 100 points. Is this possible? As a token of my thanks for the valuable information

Comment: @Asperger: LOL... nah, glad I could help. This is a Community Wiki answer, so I don't get points for it. That's how I do all my answers now. :-)

Comment: accepted your answer now since it does a lot of explaining and you did some great edits to add info, some even slightly out of the scope of my question

Comment: @Asperger: Thanks buddy. Gotta say, wish more people would write up such well formed questions as you did. And wanting to drill down to the native API gives you big thumbs-up from me as well. I started with jQuery but did exactly what you're doing. Now I use my own micro-library and haven't looked back.

Comment: absolutely agree with you. We would all spare so many kb by creating our own micro libraries. I think jquery was for a time where browser support was poor and JS support was still growing. Now most browser support all those features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89432/discussion-between-asperger-and-squint).

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
function trigger (){
  var info = this.nextElementSibling,
      getTitle = this.parentNode.firstElementChild.textContent;
  this.textContent = '-';
  info.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getTitle + 'details'));
  info.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
var open = document.getElementsByClassName('open');
for (i = 0; i < open.length; i++)
  open[i].addEventListener('click', trigger, false);
```

```js
function trigger (){
  var info = this.nextElementSibling,
      getTitle = this.parentNode.firstElementChild.textContent;
  this.textContent = '-';
  info.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getTitle + 'details'));
  info.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
var open = document.getElementsByClassName('open');
for (i = 0; i < open.length; i++)
  open[i].addEventListener('click', trigger, false);
```

```css
#a, #b {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
h1 {
  width:100%;
  font-size:160%;
  text-align:center;
}
.open {
  width:22%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:10% 0;
  line-height:0;
  font-size:150%;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:yellow;
  border-radius:100%;
}
.info {
  width:100%;
  padding:5%;
  margin:5% auto 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  background:ghostwhite;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='A'>
  <h1>Stackoverflow Question</h1>
  <div class='open'>+</div>    
  <div class='info'>Content A...</div> 
</div>
<div id='B'>
  <h1>Stackoverflow Question</h1>
  <div class='open'>+</div>    
  <div class='info'>Content B...</div> 
</div>
```

Remember that whitespace between elements becomes a text node. So better use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling` instead of `firstChild` and `nextSibling`.

Comment: Im really proud! My logic was not failing me completely : )

Comment: Any enhancement tips or something you would have done different as a more experienced programmer?

Comment: @Asperger Maybe I would use something like `this.parentNode.querySelector('.info')` instead of `this.nextElementSibling` so that changes in the order of the elements in the source code won't affect the JS.

Comment: I was thinking about that too but had no idea how to achieve this until now.   Are there any pros or cons to using sibling and querySelector? In terms of support and performance

Comment: @Asperger Maybe `querySelector` will be a bit slower because it will search in all descendants, but shouldn't matter if there isn't much content there. And it's supported since IE8, while `nextElementSibling` since IE9 (I think in previous versions of IE `nextSibling` ignored whitespaces, so it behaved more or less like `nextElementSibling`)

Comment: You are right. As long as the parentNode does not contain a large amound of elements.

Comment: My ternary operator was wrong as you removed it? Is the syntax wrong or is it simply redundant?

Comment: @Asperger It had some syntax errors, and since `h1` will always be an element, checking if it was a text node didn't make much sense. If you want it, use something like `var node = this.parentNode.firstElementChild, getTitle = node[node.nodeType == 3 ? 'nodeValue' : 'innerHTML']`

Comment: I wont use it anymore in this context as you are right. is the ternary logic useful however for performance reasons? I mean for certain dynamic situations. Lets say I somehow decided to add a image to my h1 tag (stupid but just an example) and want that to be capured as well thenn the ternary operator would do the job for me. My logic might seem off though so. Using textContent or nodeValue has a slight performance gain over innerHTML for only text for example (?)

Comment: @Asperger `nodeValue` only works with text nodes. `textContent` works for all nodes. `innerHTML` only works for element nodes. The performance is probably implementation dependent.